# How to pass parameters from C# to MATLAB?

Tags: c#, image, matlab

I want to pass an image file name as a parameter from C# to MATLAB. Here's what I have so far:

*MATLAB code*

```
function out = trial(im)
  O = imread(im);
  G = rgb2gray(O);
  imwrite(G,'output','jpeg');
  out = G;
```

*C# code*

```
private void btn_Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    }
}
```

When I browse and select an image file (*openFileDialog1.FileName*) I want to send it as the input parameter to the MATLAB function. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

For an external program to call Matlab you have to make use of the Matlab Engine, which is a standalone part of the Matlab suite. It is not possible to create a C# application and have it run code in the command window of Matlab.

A description of how to use the [Matlab Engine is found here](http://tinyurl.com/n3m7cn) (examples given in C and Fortran).

Then for your application to run the code you want you have the choice of implementing this directly into your click event, or creating a Method and calling this method from the click event.

Comment: I also found this on codeproject: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/matlabeng.aspx